# Create bootable Windows 7 DVD

Tags: windows-7, boot, dvd, bootable-media

I have a complete version of Windows 7 on my hard drive and I want to re-install Win 7 on my laptop (after 3 years of constant use).

I can't make my USB stick bootable, so I need to create a bootable DVD. How do I create a bootable DVD?

These are the files I have in the folder:

- boot
- efi
- install
- sources
- support
- upgrade
- autorun.inf
- bootmgr
- setup.exe

My Windows is original.

Comment: What guides have you tried

Answer (score 2):

Download the official trial versions of Windows 7 [here (click)](https://answers.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/wo-kann-ich-die-windows-7-iso-dateien/610a3a3c-e99c-42e6-8cf8-fda31127b035), burn the iso with the burning tool of your choice, install it and use your legit code to activate it. The original isos are bootable.

Comment: There is a related post with download links [on SU here](http://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-do-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft) as well.

Comment: @moses Didn't know that. I still would rather use a link to Microsoft where the links were supplied by a community moderator over there than use the SU one where the links were taken from a well known site dealing in warez and hacking. If the links ever go bad then chances are good that the Microsoft thread might get updated whereas the SU one probably won't.

Comment: The links in the SU post are from Digital River, which is a CDN for Microsoft.

Comment: @moses Yes, the direct download links, but check out the "sources" link below.